# Shiny - Create A Table whose cells can be toggled on and off with clicks

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to create a table whose cells can be toggled on and off by clicking and returns a data structure with the numbers of the selected cells and rows?

Something like the parental controls interface that was in windows 7 to enable and disable accounts at certain times of the day.

[image: An Interface Similar to what I want]

Comment: Just an idea here. `DT` package provides implementation of `callback` function that by monitors the cell which has been clicked, you can define the color or change the value of the table. See doc at https://github.com/rstudio/DT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, here's a solution with DT:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

toggleTable <- matrix(" ", nrow = 7, ncol = 24, 
                      dimnames = list(
                        c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), 
                        seq.int(1, 24, 1)))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$userChoiceTbl <- DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(toggleTable,
              options = list(dom = 't',
                             ordering = F),
              selection = list(target = 'cell'),
              class = 'cell-border compact') %>%
      formatStyle(1:24, cursor = 'pointer')

  })

  output$selectedInfo <- renderPrint({
    input$userChoiceTbl_cells_selected
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("userChoiceTbl", width = "50%"),
  tags$b("Cells Selected:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedInfo")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to initially set which cells are selected?

Comment: @HSchmale, yes, although I haven't tested. See section 2.1.4 "Pre-selection" of the DT Shiny page. https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html. Should be another element to the `selection` argument.

Comment: @VanceLopez This is a great solution to something similar I am working on. I'm just getting started with the DT package, and looking to setup an interface where the user can select groups of cells and name them ie., select a group of cells, enter a name in a textInput field, then select next group, assign name2 and so on. Can you give me any pointers on how to do this with DT? Thanks

Comment: @gkadam I haven't worked on this in a long time and don't have the time to test. But perhaps you could store the values for the selection and use an input to get a name. Then render a new table for a new group selection. If you wanted to show all the groups on the same table, perhaps you could color those cells a different color in another table that shows selections.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/haozhu233/dbf4cc45b5cc0e8a8397efac21e70d87

I'm using ggplot here but you can try to do it with a htmlwidget, like d3heatmap, so the color change can happen at the front end.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  weekdays <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    dt = data.frame(
      days = factor(unlist(lapply(weekdays, rep, 24)), rev(weekdays)),
      hours = 0:23,
      status = 0
    ) 
  )

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    rv$dt %>%
      mutate(status = factor(status, 0:1, c("Blocked", "Allowed"))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(hours, days, fill = status)) + 
      geom_tile(color = "white") + 
      scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), 
                         breaks = seq(-0.5, 22.5, 1), 
                         label = 0:23) + 
      scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    plot_click_x <- round(input$plot_click$x)
    plot_click_y <- factor(round(input$plot_click$y), 1:7, rev(weekdays))
    rv$dt$status[rv$dt$days == plot_click_y & rv$dt$hours == plot_click_x] <- 
      1 - rv$dt$status[rv$dt$days == plot_click_y & rv$dt$hours == plot_click_x]
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```